# Applescript create event in calendar, how do I remove the default alert?

Tags: calendar, applescript, calendar.app, osx-mountain-lion

Running 10.8 Mountain Lion, I'm trying to create a new event with Applescript like this:

```
set theDate to (current date)
tell application "Calendar"
tell calendar "Calendar"        
    set timeString to time string of theDate
    set newEvent to make new event at end with properties {description:"Last Backup", summary:"Last Backup " & timeString, location:"To a local unix system", start date:theDate, end date:theDate + 15 * minutes, allday event:false, status:confirmed}
    tell newEvent
        delete every display alarm
        delete every sound alarm
        delete every mail alarm
        delete every open file alarm
    end tell        
end tell
end tell
```

However, this does not remove the default Calendar alert which one can set through Calendar preferences (30 minutes prior in my case).

How do I create an event with no alarms at all through Applescript?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like another case of AppleScript getting the unwanted-stepchild treatment.
I suggest filing a bug with Apple.

Specifically, the buggy behavior is as follows, as of OS X 10.8.2:

```
-- Trying to set ANY properties on the *default* sound alarm fails silently.
-- Programmatically added alarms: only the trigger interval or date can be set.
repeat with al in every sound alarm of newEvent
    tell al
        -- Works only on *programmatically added* sound alarms:
        set trigger interval to -770 # The alternative option, `set trigger date to ...`, works as well.
        -- Fails silently on *all* sound alarms, whether it is the default one or a programmatically created one.
        set sound name to "Pop" # `set sound file to ...` fails equally.
    end tell
end repeat

-- This only deletes the programmatically added alarms, but never the default one.
delete sound alarms of newEvent
```

Thus, sadly, silencing the default alarm by manipulating its properties is not an option.

Comment: Still the case 7.5 years later. This is why I hate Applescript.